# ParNew and CMS-Initial Correlation

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have observed that when there is no recent ParNew and then if the CMS-Initial-Mark phase kicks-in, the CMS-Initial-Mark phase takes longer time to mark the objects in old generation.

The good part is most of the times I found ParNew (may be by chance or JVM does this internally) occurs just before CMS-Initial-Mark phase and then to mark the same number of objects in old generation, the CMS takes less time.

Would like to know the reasoning behind this observation.

Note: Considering, CMS-Initial-Mark phase is stop-the-world, the best attempt should be made to reduce its duration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally CMS initial mark piggyback on young collection. CMS can wait for young collection for some time (2 seconds default). If it is not happening, initial mark will scan all young space using single thread, this could be very time consuming.

Read http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html for more details.

HotSpot option –XX:CMSWaitDuration=<delay in ms> controls how long CMS initial mark could be delayed to piggyback young collection.

Comment: hi Alexey, thanks for your answer. Your webpage wrote "JVM configuration option –XX:CMSWaitDuration=<t> can be used to set how long CMS will wait for young space collection before start of initial marking. " -- For example, if CMSWaitDuration is 2000ms, then will it also need to wait for OldGen to be certain percentage full (e.g. CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65) in order to start initial remark of OldGen? I'm asking this some Chinese websites says CMS will only begin "initial remark" only if CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction reaches a certain % - https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/news/716357