# CMS-initial-mark took 800+ ms, it it normal?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

GC setting is:

**Min, max, total JVM size (-Xms -Xmx)**

```
JVM_SIZE="-Xms24g -Xmx24g"
```

**New Generation Sizes (-Xmn)**

```
JVM_SIZE_NEW="-Xmn2g"
```

**Type of Garbage Collector to use**

```
JVM_GC_TYPE="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC"
```

**Tuning options for the above garbage collector**

```
JVM_GC_OPTS="-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
```

Maybe 24g is too bigger for CMS?

> 2014-03-03T19:34:10.687+0800: 74.121: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1431731K(23068672K)] 3170863K(24956160K), 0.8289630 secs] [Times: user=0.83 sys=0.00, real=0.83 secs] 
>   Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.8294730 seconds

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669482/parnew-and-cms-initial-corelation

Comment: For heaps that large you should also seriously consider G1.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe 24g is too bigger for CMS?

It depends on you business, is it need that much or it could work with less that 24g.

However, the memory separated by 2 maim spaces, young and old. this two spaces are collected separately, so to enable `CMS` you need to use `‑XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

`CMS` will collect the young if its got filled or for a period of time. and there is some recommendations to set the young space as the following:

```
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize= -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

This will speed up `GC` and make it more accurate. which means that the old will not fill that fast (avoiding the Premature Promotion objects).

also for controlling `GC` delay you could use:

```
–XX:CMSWaitDuration= -delay in ms-
```

Comment: But big young size means longer young gc time cost.

Comment: Yea and you should consider to minimize you `Xmx` heap size.